# Read a text file until EOL in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a text file which has -

```
hello James!
How are you today!
```

I want to read the each character in the string till i find EOL character.As i am using windows where i have /n/r which represents EOL character.How can i write a condition to go through all the characters of the string and print them one by one till it reaches EOL(/n/r).

```
int readedValue;

do
{   
    while((readedValue = bufferReader.read()) != 10)
   {
    //readedValue = bufferReader.read();
    char ch = (char) readedValue;
    System.out.print(ch);
   } 

}
while ((readedValue = bufferReader.read()) != -1);
```

when i read the file now , i get out put as hello James!ow are you today!

I am not getting 'H'ow in How. What can i alter this to get the complete text?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `readLine()` method until it returns `null`?

Comment: `while (line.charAt(21)!='\n' && line.charAt(22)!='\r')` this is an infinite loop, or an exception, or never runs.

Comment: readLine will give you all characters except for the "\n" at the end. Also the file IO is abstracted, whether you're using windows or some other OS, the file IO should behave the same (idealy)

Comment: yes its an infinite loop! So how can reach the end of the string and check whether that character is a EOL character?

Comment: @james It won't be. readLine() discards the newline. If you want, you can do `line=line+"\n";`. Then the last character is a newline. The end of the string is always `line.charAt(line.length()-1);`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

Comment: Instead of using readline() , Is there any way i can use buffer reader to read each character and print them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that:

```
while((line=input.readLine())!=null) {
    // do something
}
```

---

If you want to read char by char, you can use this:

```
int readedValue;
while ((readedValue = reader.read()) != -1) {
    char ch = (char) readedValue;
    // do something
}
```

---

Here is an example (with a string instead a file) for your new problem:

```
String line;
int readedValue;
String s = "hello James!\n\rHow are you today!";
StringReader input = new StringReader(s);
BufferedReader lineReader= new BufferedReader (input);

while((line=lineReader.readLine())!=null) {
    StringReader input2 = new StringReader(line);
    BufferedReader charReader= new BufferedReader (input2);
    while((readedValue = charReader.read()) != -1) {
        char ch = (char) readedValue;
        System.out.print(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the line has more than 20 characters?

Comment: That doesn't matter! This code snippet read one line after another until it reads `null`. It reas a whole line and not only 20 characters!

Comment: I have edited the code , can you let me know if there is a solution for the above problem?

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you accept it as your solution please?

Answer (score 1):

As people have noted, the `readline()` method reads to the next line separator, and returns the line with the separator removed.  So your tests for `'\n'` and `'\r'` in `line` cannot possibly evaluate to `true`.

But you can easily add an extra end-of-line when you output the `line` string<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - that is, unless you actually need to preserve the exact same end-of-line sequence characters as in the input stream.</sup>

You ask:

> Instead of using `readline()`, Is there any way i can use buffer reader to read each character and print them?

Yea, sure.  The `read()` method returns either one character or `-1` to indicate EOF.  So:

```
    int ch = br.read();
    while (ch != -1) {
       System.out.print((char) ch);
       ch = br.read();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is about magic numbers.

your while will enter into an infinite loop in the case charAt(21)!='\n' && charAt(22)!='\r'

those two integers shall be increased inside the loop.

```
charAt(i)!='\n' && charAt(i+1)!='\r'
::inside loop
  i++
```

Comment: Instead of using readline() , Is there any way i can use buffer reader to read each character and print them?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read(char[], int, int)